# How can I find and modify an application launcher in 18.04 because tuxmath seg faults in fullscreen mode?

Tags: launcher

This was happening in 16.04 but I was hoping that an upgrade to the latest everything would fix it.  I installed tuxmath using "apt install" and it shows up in the Applications menu so I added it to my favorites and now have an icon in the bar.  However when I click the icon the program starts to work then crashes just before the menu items appear.  When I run from a command line the output is

```
libpng warning: Interlace handling should be turned on when using png_read_image
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I find that if I run in windowed mode everything is fine, but I really need to modify the launcher for the kids.  How do I add the -w to the command initiated by the icon in the launcher?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should find it in `/usr/share/applications/` or in `~/.local/share/applications/`.

It is generally not recommended to modify files in root directory. If an associated package gets updated the file will most probably be overwritten.

So if you find the launcher in `/usr/share/applications/`, first copy it to `~/.local/share/applications/`. Open the copied file with a text editor and `-w` to the `Exec=` line.